# Query Using XMLEXISTS Incorrectly Has "If Any" Behavior (Oracle 11g)

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g, xmltype

I'm working on a project which involves querying the contents on an XML document. I've come up with a simplified test case (below) to try and understand how it works. The problem is that the haskey field is true for every record if even one record has that tag. How do I get it to return true/false based on the existence of that child node in each record individually?

```
DECLARE
  players xmltype := xmltype(' 
<Players>
  <Player username="player1">
    <HasKey></HasKey>
  </Player>
  <Player username="player2">
    <HasKey></HasKey>
  </Player>
  <Player username="player3">
  </Player>
</Players>');
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
  (SELECT username,
    (
    CASE
      WHEN xmlexists('$p/Players/Player/HasKey' passing players AS "p")
      THEN 'TRUE'
      ELSE 'FALSE'
    END) haskey
  FROM xmltable('/Players/Player' passing Players columns username VARCHAR2(30) path '@username' ) "p"
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(c.username ||','|| c.haskey);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I also tried ...xmlexists('$p/Players/Player[@username="$u"]/HasKey' passing players AS "p", username as "u")... but that returns haskey=false for every record.

Comment: I found a workaround by using nested for cursor loops. The outer loop breaks the document down into smaller chunks by player. That way there's only one potential HasKey tag per xmltype document. The inner loop processes each sub document in turn. BUT, there's got to be a cleaner way to do this!